# Pandas - read CSV with spanish characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame which has column with spanish regions, when I import the .csv as following

```
df = pd.read_csv('...',delimiter=';',decimal=',')
```

And print the content of column, I see this: Castilla y Le�n.

I could not find a way how to fix it, but I am assuming there is smart way how to do it.

Comment: Try the `encoding` parameter [from the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 3):

`read_csv` has an optional argument called `encoding` that deals with the way your characters are encoded.

You can give a try to:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('...', delimiter = ';', decimal = ',', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Otherwise, you have to check how your characters are encoded (It is one of [them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)).

You can read the doc of `read_csv` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

The solution was posted in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43684587/9214357)

You need:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 2):

When using MacOs try this:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='maccentraleurope')
```

From: [Python Codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Spanish dataframe and I use the `latin-1` encoding.

```
df = pd.read_csv('...', delimiter = ';', decimal = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')
```